# Labels are not showing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

The coastline (the data I'm using) is including the small islands (Tarakan and Laut), I wanted to create two labels for these islands. The attribute table itself doesn't have specific names, so for this, I inserted a column named `name_hoel` in the attribute table, after setting, it shows me only the 'Laut', but NOT 'Tarakan'.

What shall I do to make both islands name appear? (at a scale 25 Mio.)

Layer Properties>Labels>Rendering and the box says: "Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)"---- checked! but it is still not showing.

image: 1) coastline with wanted islands (in yellow)

[image]

2. it should look like this (please ignore its color):

[image]

3. Layer Properties: 'placement' and 'rendering'

[image]
[image]

Comment: please show us an image of your Labels tab in Layer Properties

Comment: @firefly-orange  Hi I've added it to my 'question', you can see it now

Comment: What happens if you turn off all the data defined stuff and except the default values?

Comment: @firefly-orange yes, it shows me the labels now, but still, I needed to do this in properties>Text>size: 5*(25000000/@map_scale). then the size of the label will stay the same(when zoom-out and zoom-in). any suggestion?

Comment: under size, set the size to points not map units

Comment: @firefly-orange in Text > Size > they are as in Points NOT map units.